# Use cases for read-only screen

Tags: user-stories, requirements

I'm looking into use cases and user stories topics, and I have difficulties to properly define those for a project.

Although it's quick and straightforward on user goals such as 'perform this', 'perform that' etc... I have a screen where the user does not have any transactional activity, but instead reporting or read-only screens.

Let's take an example: I have a dashboard with numbers to get the amount of rent achieved this months, etc.

What would be a great use case for this? At first, I was asking 'why would the user need to access this screen?', in order to understand where it fits to adjust the strategy. So a possible use case could be: Assess rental achievable.

Last, in this screen, a user can filter data, like seeing its amount for a particular country state. Is this part of a use case? Or part of the previous use case? If the latter option, what would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of use cases your 'assess rental achievement' seems fine (perhaps monitor rather than assess?) - I guess the acceptance criteria is where you will flesh out your KPIs for this screen so that you can logically keep all your detail about this screen in one use case.

Detailing this seems to logically fall into acceptance criterias so **I would suggest acceptance criteria like 'test that user can see all rents achieved', 'test that user can filter by country state', 'test that user can sort information up/down by clicking on column headers' and so on.**

It may be that these acceptance criteria then naturally pan out as user stories: 'as an administrator I can see all rents achieved', as an administrator I can filter by country state so that I can focus on problem areas' and so on.